# Java reflection - Casting Field to Swing Inputs

Tags: java, swing, casting, refactoring

I am trying to access all public fields in a class extending JPanel so i can reset them but I can't cast a field to a `JCheckBox`, `JTextArea` etc.

Here's my attempt

```
public void clearPage(JPanel page) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException
{
  //Basic class using Swing elements (JtextFields, JCheckBoxes etc.)
  Field[]  inputs   = page.getClass().getFields(); //Works, I get all Fields

  for (int i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  {
      if (inputs[i].getType().getName().equals("javax.swing.JCheckBox"))//Works
      {
          JCheckBox demo = (JCheckBox) inputs[i]; //(Cannot cast from Field to JCheckBox)

          //Second Try 
          //JCheckBox str = (JCheckBox) Class.forName("javax.swing.JCheckBox").cast(inputs[i]);
          //str.setSelected(false);
          //Cannot cast java.lang.reflect.Field to javax.swing.JCheckBox
     }
  }
}
```

I just need to have access to the inputs 'sub' methods:
`.SetText`
`.setSelected`
etc.

I've been trying to get the methods I need using this method:

```
Method d = inputs[i].getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
inputs[i].getType().getClass().getMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
```

But they both are giving me the error that their is no method by that name.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good use of reflection and indicates a design problem with how you've written your objects. (Too many fields?) You should probably use an array or something instead. Reflection is for writing generalized API for things like debugging and serialization. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244864.

Comment: Thanks for the links, the reason there is so many is because the program I'm making is for a first line tech support department that needs a large amount of GUI fields so it can generate an escalation template to the second line team. I'll take a look at the XY link, it looks useful for posting questions.

Comment: Well, hence my suggestion to use something like an array. If you have a lot of GUI fields, then the approach which is more likely to be correct is to have (roughly speaking) a `class Widget {}` and a `List<Widget>`, where `Widget` is some type representing the common factors of all fields. Some other helpful links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZh5LMaSmE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-2yFMzxqwU which are two videos demonstrating many facets of good object-oriented program design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do it using `Field` then you should do it like:

```
JCheckBox demo =  (JCheckBox) inputs[i].get(page);
```

You wont be able to case `Field` to a `JCheckBox`, you need to first get the value, and then you can cast it and hence you would need to call `get` method on the panel under which this check box is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm getting an odd error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.swing.JCheckBox field LTE_NoConnection_CatSix.chckbxWifiOn_YES to TicketBuilder
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
 Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: `Can not set javax.swing.JCheckBox field LTE_NoConnection_CatSix.chckbxWifiOn_YES to TicketBuilder` this is a different issue then what you raised originially and i can't comment further without looking at your code.

Comment: Sorry your answer was right, where 'this' is i put the 'page' was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I clicked on the tick (I assume that chooses your answer) and I can't close the question until i have 200 points it looks like. I will close it another time, thanks again for the help.